# How can I get tidy to allow my custom attributes?

Tags: php, html, custom-attributes, tidy

```
function myTidy($content) {
    $tidyConfig = array(
        'indent'                        => false, //don't indent
        'doctype'                       => 'omit', //don't include doctype
        'wrap'                          => 0, // don't line wrap
        'show-body-only'                => true, //don't include <html><head><title><body>
        'drop-proprietary-attributes'   => false, //this doesn't seem to be helping with our youtube stuff...
    );
    $tidy = tidy_parse_string($content, $tidyConfig, 'UTF8');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();
    return (string)$tidy;
}


echo myTidy('<span _my_custom_attr="asdfsdf">asdf</span>'), "\n";
```

Desired output

```
<span _my_custom_attr="asdfsdf">asdf</span>
```

Actual output:

```
<span>asdf</span>
```

What does it take to get tidy to allow my custom attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a leading underscore make the attibute invalid, so tidy will remove it, even if your tell him not to remove unknown attributes.

Comment: Even in the SO syntax highlighter the underscore isn't hightlighted correctly :)

Comment: Yep.  That's what tipped me off to try removing it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out removing the leading underscore in the attribute name resolves the issue -- `my_custom_attr` works fine.